# Blogger gadet - display in a post only

Tags: google-gadget

When implementing a gadget, is there a setting that would tell blogger to display the gadget in a post (or on a homepage) only?

I know that one can add conditional tags to the template html but that's NOT what I'm after. I need to figure out a way how to do this via the gadget's code so that the end user doesn't need to interfere with any code to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured that this isn't possible.

A workaround I've come up with is to set the gadget's default height to 0, then use javascript to find out whether we're on a homepage or an individual post and then, depending on the requirement, resize the gadget to the desired height. In such case, it is necessary to include the `<Require feature="dynamic-height"/>` in the ModulePref section of the xml file and use the `gadgets.window.adjustHeight()` function.

The caveat with this workaround is that the gadget, event when its height is set to 0, will take at least 10px in height.